# SQL server 2016 connecting to SQL Management Studio

Tags: sql-server, iis, sql-management-studio

I am using a SQL Server Management Console and the SQL Server 2016 Evaluation edition trying to connect a local server on Windows 10. I am connecting to an Azure cloud instance cluster because I have a local instance I would like but also connecting with the same error. I have enabled my services: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/master-data-services/install-windows/web-application-requirements-master-data-services?view=sql-server-2017.  I get the error message:

```
Unable to connect to localhost. The target server does not have the SMTP service installed. You cannot manage an IIS 7.5 Web or FTP server by using Internet Information Services (6.0) Manager.
```

I am taking a class of my SQL and can't get a server up.  I have a lot of SQL experience in MYSQL which I can just use the console.  I'm a administrator and went to the manage.iss.net for the set-up but on localhost:55539 I don't know the login.  Also, checked .NET on my machine to be current with running on a new Windows 10.  When I look for Windows Authorization on settings I don't think they kept it with this home edition operating system. I am running 5 programs at once to find the right setting I need.I can see that I am running when I look at my services.
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you quite sure that you're launching SQL Server Management Studio?  From the error message, it appears that you're actually launching Internet Information Services (6.0) Manager.

Comment: Yes.  When I use SQL Server to set-up my database it complains my server isn't correct and turn on web services.  The problem for not connecting is what is above.

Comment: @Charles Burge I updated the applications that are all being used to get SQL Server 2016 working

Comment: Why is the logon for `NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON`? You must have created an administrator login when installing SQL Server. If you have not created your login when installing SQL Server, then [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9889334/how-do-i-grant-myself-admin-access-to-a-local-sql-server-instance) might help, but it might be easier to uninstall and reinstall, not skipping the steps of creating logins. You also don't need Active Directory for a single-computer installation and omitting it might avoid some complexities.

Comment: @harrymc I am the administrator using the correct admin server address. Where that is coming from is only in the message.  I don't know why it would mean anything but connecting to an administrator account because that's all I created. Also, I have launched this before by needing to start the deamon and you'll notice that has a logon unlike the other authorizations.

Comment: I think you are referring to the last image, where I believe you are not going through Active Directory (correct me if I'm wrong). Is that a local or network login?

Comment: So neither is working. What you are seeing is a local instance with an authentication that in someway isn't seeing the server nor connecting to the running daemon.  I get  this from Azure cloud instance as well. Correcting you as I am using my AD. @harrymc

Comment: I'm trying to understand if local login not through AD and on same computer does work.

Comment: I can login locally fine.@harrymc

Answer (score 0):

As you can login locally to SQL Server, but only experience the problem when
going through Active Directory, there is something lacking with your domain
login.

There are multiple reasons for such a problem. A couple of them are listed
below:

- You need to grant the AD domain the right to login to SQL Server.
  To add the login to a fixed database role, you could use:

  ```
  USE YourDatabase
  GO
  ALTER ROLE db_owner ADD MEMBER 'DOMAIN\login'
  ```

  For more details and an alternative using the GRANT command,
  see the post
  [Why Does A/D Account Need SQL Server Login?](https://serverfault.com/questions/457798/why-does-a-d-account-need-sql-server-login)
- Some sources suggest that problems might arise when trying to login to
  SQL Server from a different Windows login, as SSMS is pretty touchy on
  this point.
  It is worth checking if this is indeed the problem.

Comment: So I don't understand as I use older SQL Server this is a database created in a SQL Management Configuration with a wizard so I can't get to it from commandline.  I've administered the Database but can't seem to get create database to be authenticated in this case with SQL Server 2016 Eval Edition.

Comment: The above is information that can help, but making it work needs local access, which only you have.

Comment: I just added a Rule. The question is what setting I want in this specific kind of out dated software.